# Kurdistan, Iraq, including Sulemania, for Resident Visa HCV Hepatitis quality and quantity

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, residency, medical-tourism, iraqi-kurdistan

If an applicant's HCV Hepatitis Test shows a positive result, do the government and medical centers in Kurdistan, Iraq, including Sulemania,  immediately reject the visa application, or does the applicant go under further assessment to determine both the quality and quantity of the virus present in the bloodstream?